# Android build mini navigation drawer with Icons

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-custom-view, materialdrawer

I want to build a fixed mini nav drawer in android. will will always be visible an not extendable, with icons only.

Something like https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer Mini Drawer.
I try used his library, but I can't figured out how to make it fixed.

here is my code:

```
private Drawer result = null;
private MiniDrawer miniResult = null;


result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("2").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withBadge("22").withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle(Color.RED, Color.RED)).withIdentifier(2).withSelectable(false),
                           new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        new ToggleDrawerItem().withName("3").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withChecked(true).withOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)
                ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName().getText(MainActivity.this), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withGenerateMiniDrawer(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                // build only the view of the Drawer (don't inflate it automatically in our layout which is done with .build())
                .buildView();


        miniResult = result.getMiniDrawer();
        View view = miniResult.build(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the normal usage there is always the "normal" drawer (via the `DrawerLayout`), and the `MiniDrawer` in your case you just want to use the `MiniDrawer` and add it to your `View` hierarchy.

As you already figured out correctly the `MiniDrawer` is filled via the normal `DrawerBuilder` as this comes with all the methods to interact with the elements added to the drawer.

As your use-case is special there is no "out-of-the-box" inflating of the `MiniDrawer` alone.

So you have the `View` of the `MiniDrawer` above. You now just need to add it to your `Activity` .

I recommend that your layout looks something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Place your content here -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in your code you get the "container"

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(view, 0); //view is the view of your MiniDrawer
```

---

Just to improve your code and remove unnecessary stuff. You can remove

```
.withToolbar(toolbar)
.withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
```

as those are not necessary if you just use the `MiniDrawer`

Comment: The width of the mini drawer is too big, is there away to manually customize it? Thanks for your comment I really appreciate it.

Comment: So you need less than `72dp`? All of the `MiniDrawer` is optimized and defined for those `72dp` it is possible to change it, but will require a bit more work

Comment: So it sounds it is working now. So you might accept the answer, and open a new question on how to change the width of the `MiniDrawer` will add a detailed answer for the new question too, later today. Will help others too

Answer (score 0):

In the docs for that library the developer mentioned that you can [lock the drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#can-i-lock-the-drawer). Could you try that out and see if it prevents it from opening?

```
result = new DrawerBuilder()...
...
//get the DrawerLayout from the Drawer
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = result.getDrawerLayout();
//do whatever you want with the Drawer. Like locking it. 
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Also try the other lock modes defined [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#constants) if LOCK_MODE_CLOSED doesn't work and let us know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

You can create view for your drawer like this way,try to use [ActionsContentView](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView)

```
<shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/divider"
        app:actions_layout="@layout/actions"
        app:actions_spacing="0dp"
        app:content_layout="@layout/content"
        app:shadow_drawable="@drawable/shadow"
        app:shadow_width="8dip"
        app:spacing="64dip"
        app:spacing_type="right_offset" />
```

OR try to use [Partial SlidingPaneLayout](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/01/partial-slidingpanelayout.html)