# MaterialDrawer How to customize mini drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-custom-view, materialdrawer

I am trying to figured out how to customize MaterialDrawer by https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

At moment the width is too big. 
I want to make width  smaller  with bigger icons to cover the spaces and change the background color.

This App will be for tablet only. 
thanks.

Here is my drawer:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Place your content here -->

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="215dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("2").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withBadge("22").withBadgeStyle(new BadgeStyle(Color.RED, Color.RED)).withIdentifier(2),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("3").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(3)
                ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ((Nameable) drawerItem).getName().getText(MainActivity.this), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withGenerateMiniDrawer(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                // build only the view of the Drawer (don't inflate it automatically in our layout which is done with .build())
                .buildView();


        miniResult = result.getMiniDrawer();
        View view = miniResult.build(this);

        LinearLayout  container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.addView(view, 0); //view is the view of your MiniDrawer
```

Image:
[image]

I want to build something like this:
[image]

Thanks

I originally asked a question in how to enable a fixed mini drawer here
[Android build mini navigation drawer with Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38342407/3696500)

Comment: so you want not only to make it smaller but also bigger than the original 72dp?

Comment: Yeah, I want to be able to manually change the width of the mini drawer. and then later make the icons to math the drawer width .

Comment: do you need additional information?

Comment: done, thanks for your help, Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on versions **>= v5.3.5**

First we have to define the width for the `MiniDrawer` itself. In the code samples shown below we will configure the `MiniDrawer` and it's item to take **144dp**. I recommend to do this before adding the `View` to your layout as shown in this sample.

```
//get the MiniDrawer
MiniDrawer miniDrawer = result.getMiniDrawer();
//build it and get the view
View miniDrawerView = miniDrawer.build(this);
//define the width (You could also do it via the LayoutParams
miniDrawerView.setMinimumWidth((int) UIUtils.convertDpToPixel(144, this));
//add the MiniDrawer to your view hirachy
findViewById(R.id.frame_container)).addView(miniDrawerView, 0);
```

After you have added the `MiniDrawer` view itself to your layout you want to define the changed dimensions of the `MiniDrawerItems` you can do this via your `dimens.xml` file by defining the following:

```
<!-- required for a changed size -->
<!-- 144dp = the full width of the MiniDrawer -->
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item">144dp</dimen>
<!-- 144dp - 8dp padding around = 128dp -->
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_icon">128dp</dimen>
<!-- 144dp - 16dp padding around = 112dp -->
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_profile_icon">112dp</dimen>

<!-- optional configurable dimensions -->
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_padding">4dp</dimen>
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_padding_sides">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_icon_padding">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_badge_text">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="material_mini_drawer_item_profile_icon_padding">16dp</dimen>
```

After this your `MiniDrawer` and the items will be displayed in the correct size.